# Difference between app.application and Setup.exe

Tags: c#, clickonce

Click Once generates two files when it publishes an application i.e. app.application and Setup.exe.  Running both these files appears to have the same effect.  What is the difference between these files? Does ClickOnce install anything on a users PC?

Also is there a way to run a batch file when click once starts and ends?

Comment: I suggest editing to remove the final question, and asking a new one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.application is a manifest file containing details about the application to be deployed.

Setup.exe is a setup launcher/bootstrapper provided by the framework.  It reads manifest data in the clickonce source folder and effects the necessary changes on the clients machine to enable the app run.

There are two deployment modes for clickonce - Offline and Online.  In the online mode, nothing "permanent" is put on the client's machine. The app is always run from the deployment location.  In offline mode, the application files are copied to a designated location under the users' profile and they run from there whether or not there is a connection available to the deployment source.  A short cut is also added to the user's startmenu and optionally to the desktop for easy launching of the app. The folder where clickonce apps are installed, is located at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0.  Note that no changes made are system wide.

I am not aware of a way to run batch files before/after the clickonce process ends.  What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Extra info: if you ticked anything in the 'Prerequisites' dialog of the Visual Studio publish wizard, then your users will need to run the .exe rather than the .application file. The .exe checks/installs the prerequisites, then runs the .application file afterwards.